# Issues deploying microsoft bot framework to heroku with docker

Tags: c#, azure, docker, heroku, botframework

I am new to Docker and C# and am trying to deploy the microsoft bot framework to Heroku with Docker

I am using this pre built example :

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot
 i have updated the app setting with the correct Luis credential. I have created an azure bot service with this endpoint : `https://mybotfram.herokuapp.com/api/messages`

```
Then i updated the bot service credential in the app setting json. 

{
  "MicrosoftAppId": "****************************************",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "********************",
  "LuisAppId": "********************",
  "LuisAPIKey": "********************",
  "LuisAPIHostName": "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
}
```

My folder has this look :

[image]

Then to the right folder :

```
heroku container:login
heroku create myrepeat
heroku container:push web --app mybotfram
heroku container:release web --app mybotfram
```

My Dockerfile looks like this :

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ./*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY ./. .
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
# COPY ./*.bot ./
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoreBot.dll"]
```

The endpoint does not work and I am getting this error in Heroku logs, it seems like nothing is working properly.

```
2019-10-30T15:23:32.220067+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/api/messages" host=mybotfram.herokuapp.com request_id=edda2c79-ab2e-4258-8a17-38a145f06f06 fwd="13.94.246.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-30T15:25:52.90006+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/api/messages" host=mybotfram.herokuapp.com request_id=387e5fcf-7330-45f9-8751-d3c156618565 fwd="13.94.246.37" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-30T15:33:14.734976+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mybotfram.herokuapp.com request_id=5b7a5fe7-9371-4911-a563-d3aeba8411c4 fwd="84.101.210.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-30T15:33:14.383936+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/messages" host=mybotfram.herokuapp.com request_id=75836fb3-afca-4725-9b00-1ffcdec0e2a1 fwd="84.101.210.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

As mentioned I am new to this, so any insights on the above would be greatly appreciated!

---

_________________________________________EDIT__________________________________

---

Editing after the answer Mdrichardson (thanks a lot!).

Here the way I rewrote my Program.cs based on your input.

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
                        .UseKestrel()
                        .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"))
                        .Build()
                        .Run();
                }


        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging((logging) =>
                {
                    logging.AddDebug();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There's a full how-to below this section

**For you, specifically:**

503 errors usually indicate your client can't communicate with the bot.

My guess is that you need to update your `Program.cs` to contain this:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"))
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

Heroku provides the exposed port via the `PORT` environment variable. Your bot just needs to listen on it.

**If that doesn't work for you, I recommend starting from scratch and following the tutorial below**

---

Got this working, from scratch.

## How to Dockerize Your Bot and Deploy to Heroku

The majority of the credit for this should go to [Victor Reyes for this article](https://medium.com/faun/how-to-dockerize-a-net-core-application-and-deploy-it-to-heroku-893978bc444b), since I basically did the same thing, but with a bot.

The following tutorial will cover the basics and assumes you know a bit about developing bots. See the article for more details on the Docker/Heroku side and [our official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for the bot side of things.

**1.** Download
    [CoreBot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot).

**2.** Update `appsettings.json` with your bot and LUIS information.

**3.** Run the app locally and verify that it works in
    [Emulator](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-emulator). This
    tests that your bot works at all.

**4.** Create a dockerfile in the root folder with your `.csproj`. It
    should look like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2.300-alpine3.9 as server

ENV ASPNETCORE_Environment=Production
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:3978

WORKDIR /server
VOLUME ./wwwroot/Repository
COPY . ./

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o publish

EXPOSE 3978/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","publish/CoreBot.dll"]
```

**5.** From the root folder with your `.csproj` file, run `docker build -t <dockerImageName>:<tag> .`

**6.** Run `docker run -p 3978:3978 <dockerImageName>:<tag>`

**7.** Run the app locally and verify that it works in [Emulator](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-emulator). This tests that your bot works as a Docker image.

**8.** Update your dockerfile so that it now looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2.300-alpine3.9 as server

ENV ASPNETCORE_Environment=Production

WORKDIR /server
COPY . ./

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o publish

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","publish/CoreBot.dll"]
```

**9.** Overwrite `Main()` in `Program.cs` so that it contains:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"))
        .Build()
        .Run();
}
```

**10.** Run the following:

```
heroku login
heroku container:login
docker login --username=_ --password=$(heroku auth:token) registry.heroku.com
```

**11.** [Create a Heroku App](https://dashboard.heroku.com/new-app) and remember its

**12.** Run:

```
docker build -t registry.heroku.com/<appName>/web .
docker push registry.heroku.com/<appName>/web
heroku container:release web --app <appName>
```

**13.** Test in Emulator by using `https://<appName>.herokuapp.com/api/messages` and your `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword`

*Note: Depending on your environment you may need to use `0.0.0.0:3978` as opposed to `localhost:3978`. It may also be worth trying `127.0.0.1:3978`.*

Comment: Thanks a lot mdrichardson ! This is very helpful. I am having some trouble still, i will try to figure it out first

Comment: @GuillaumeLabs You're welcome. Your `Program.cs` looks exactly like mine, so that's not the issue. What problem are you running into?

Comment: It might be an issue with your `heroku` commands, too. I'm not super familiar with heroku, but I see that our commands are different.

Comment: thanks to you, i could successfully deploy the code on Heroku.  This worked perfectly ! Luis was not working anymore, but this was another issues related to credentials.

Comment: in my case, I used EchoBot but kept running into the "cannot assign requested address" errors. it turns out echobot was connecting to localhost:52148 and in order to hook that up, you start the docker container with --network=host  and  then you need a listener on your host that transports all traffic on 52148 over to the machine that the emulator is listening on. in my case:  ssh user@host -L3978:localhost:3978 -R 52148:localhost:52148 did the trick.

Comment: @nmishr Ah yeah, if the bot is using a different port, definitely need to take that into account. Glad you got it working!